# .concatMap() start the next Observable but previous one was not finished

Tags: java, android, rx-java, concatmap

I'm using RxJava on Android. 
I have a pretty quite simple piece of code here : 
Observable> observable =

```
Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Observable<Boolean>>) emitter1 -> {
                            emitter1.onNext(doSomething());
                            emitter1.onComplete();
                        }).concatMap(accessToken -> Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Observable<Boolean>>) emitter2 -> {                                                            
                            emitter2.onNext(doSomethingElse());
                            emitter2.onComplete();
                        }).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
```

What I want to do =>

```
-> Start A
    -> A is processing
    -> A is ending
-> Start B
    -> B is processing
    -> B is ending
```

what I actually got :

```
-> Start A 
   -> A is processing
-> Start B
   -> B is processing
-> A is ending
-> B is ending
```

But I thougt concatMap was waiting for the first observable to end before lauching the next one... ?

Comment: That is `concatWith`. `concatMap` turns the main source's onNext value into an inner sources and runs one of them at a time.

Comment: If I use concatWith, only my first Observable is called but not the second one... :/

Comment: Remove the `accessToken -> `.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this :

```
Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Observable<Boolean>>) emitter1 -> {
                            emitter1.onNext(doSomething());
                            emitter1.onComplete();
                        }).concatMap(accessToken -> Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Observable<Boolean>>) emitter2 -> {                                                            
                            emitter2.onNext(doSomethingElse());
                            emitter2.onComplete();
                    })).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```